# Function figuring out which close-by value comes from which input value

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I would like to optimize the below `traceback` function. This function is part of an elementary step of the program and is called a lot...

```
import numpy as np

def traceback(tuple_node, tuple_node_alt):
    """
    Compute which value from tuple_node_alt comes from which value from tuple_node.
    Return a dictionnary where the key are the values from tuple_node and the values are the idx at which
    the value may be located in tuple_node_alt.
    """
    # Compute the tolerances based on the node
    tolerances = [0.1 if x <= 100 else 0.2 for x in tuple_node]

    # Traceback
    distance = dict()
    alt_identification = dict()
    for k, x in enumerate(tuple_node):
        distance[k] = [abs(elt-1) for elt in [alt_x/x for alt_x in tuple_node_alt]]
        alt_identification[x] = list(np.where([elt <= tolerances[k]+0.00001 for elt in distance[k]])[0])

    # Controls the identification and corrects it
    len_values = {key: len(val) for key, val in alt_identification.items()}

    if all([x <= 1 for x in len_values.values()]):
        return alt_identification
    else:
        for key, value in alt_identification.items():
            if len(value) <= 1:
                continue
            else:
                other_values = [val for k, val in alt_identification.items() if k != key]
                if value in other_values:
                   continue
                else:
                    for val in other_values:
                        set1 = set(value)
                        intersec = set1.intersection(set(val))
                        if len(intersec) == 0:
                            continue
                        else:
                            alt_identification[key] = [v for v in value if v not in intersec]

    return alt_identification
```

The input is composed of 2 tuples which do not need to have the same size. e.g.

```
tuple_node = (40, 50, 60, 80)
tuple_node_alt = (87, 48, 59, 39)
```

The goal is to figure out which value from `tuple_node_alt` may come from which value from `tuple_node`. If the value from `tuple_node_alt` is within a 10% margin from a value from `tuple_node`, it is considered that it comes from this value.

e.g. 39 is within a 10% margin of 40. It comes from 40.
This aprt is perform in the "Traceback" section, where a distance dictionnary is computed and where the idx are computed. With the example above, the output is:

```
Out[67]: {40: [3], 50: [1], 60: [2], 80: [0]}
```

However, because of a potential overlapping of the tolerance band, 3 scenarios exists:

**Scenario 1**: each value has been identified to one alternative value. That's the case above.

**Scenario 2:**

```
tuple_node = (40, 50, 60, 80)
tuple_node_alt = (42, 55, 54)
```

55 and 54 are both in the tolerance band of both 50 and 60. Thus, the output is:

```
Out[66]: {40: [0], 50: [1, 2], 60: [1, 2], 80: []}
```

**Scenario 3:**

```
tuple_node = (40, 50, 60)
tuple_node_alt = (42, 55, 59)
```

This is when the control part comes in play. With this input, `alt_identification` becomes: `Out[66]: {40: [0], 50: [1], 60: [1, 2], 80: []}`. However, the 55 can not come from 60 since 50 only has one possibility: 55. Thus, this number being already taken, the correct output which is provided through the control & correct section is:

```
Out[66]: {40: [0], 50: [1], 60: [2], 80: []}
```

I would really like to optimize this part and to make it a lot more quicker. At the moment, it takes:

```
# With an input which does not enter the control & correct part.
node = (40, 50, 60, 80)
node_alt = (39, 48, 59, 87)
%timeit traceback(node, node_alt)
22.6 µs ± 1.04 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

# With an input which need correction
node = (40, 50, 60, 100)
node_alt = (42, 55, 59, 89)
%timeit traceback(node, node_alt)
28.1 µs ± 1.88 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of low-hanging fruit inefficiencies:

1. `distance = dict()`.  The `distance[k]` value is computed in a loop, and only every used in the next statement of the loop.  It does not need to be stored in a dictionary.
2. `all([ ...list comprehension... ])`: You are using list comprehension to build up a list, which you immediately pass to `all(...)`.  There is no need to actually create the list.  Just use `all(...list comprehension...)`.
3. `set1 = set(value)`.  This is inside a `for val in other_values:` loop, where `value` and `set1` are not changed.  Move the statement out of the `for` loop, to avoid recreating the same set each iteration.
4. `len_values` is only used in the afore mentioned `all(...)`, and only the the values of `len_values` dictionary are used.  As such, the `len_value` dictionary construction is also unnecessary, and the `if` statement can be written:

   ```
   if all(len(val) <= 1 for val in alt_identification.values()):
   ```

---

Since you are returning `alt_identification` from the `if` statement, and after the `if...else` statement, you can invert the test, and remove one return statement:

```
if any(len(val) > 1 for val in alt_identification.values()):
    for key, value in alt_identification.items():
        # ... omitted for brevity ...

return alt_identification
```

Similarly, the two `if condition: continue else:` could be re-written `if not condition:`.

---

Other possible improvements:

- `tolerances[k]` is only used in next `for k` loop.  The list can be removed and the calculations move into the loop.
- `numpy` is only used for a `list(np.where([...])[0])` operation, which is fairly obfuscated.  A simple list comprehension can be used instead.
- The values of `alt_identification` are of type `list`, and converted (repeatedly) into a `set()` in the "control & correct" code.  They could be stored as `set()` to avoid repeated conversions.

Here is my rework of the code, with the changes based on above comments:

```
def traceback(tuple_node, tuple_node_alt):

    def close_alternates(x):
        tolerance = (0.1 if x <= 100 else 0.2) + 0.00001
        return set( k for k, alt_x in enumerate(tuple_node_alt)
                    if abs(alt_x/x - 1) <= tolerance )

    alt_identification = { x: close_alternates(x) for x in tuple_node }   

    if any(len(val) > 1 for val in alt_identification.values()):
        for key, values in alt_identification.items():
            if len(values) > 1:
                other_values = [val for k, val in alt_identification.items() if k != key]
                if values not in other_values:
                    for other in other_values:
                        alt_identification[key] -= other

    return alt_identification
```

I'm getting up to a 2.8x speedup with the above code, on your test data set that require correction.